# why isn't onTrigger invoking on collision with a trigger or a rigidbody?

Tags: unity

```
void onTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Pick Up")) 
    {
        other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        count = count + 1;
        setCountText ();
    }
}
```

This is the methodI want to invoke, on collision of a sphere with another cube. The cube is set as a trigger, and a rigidbody component is attached to both of the objects. Still, on collision, the method is not invoked. Is there anything else that may be done, for this method to execute?

Comment: @Archmede, I am assuming you added spacing to this code excerpt, and added inline format to the answer. If that is the case, I must apologise for rejecting your edits, and humbly request you provide more in an edit, in the future; as was displayed to me, I could not tell any difference. The spaces were displayed as being *removed*, and the inline code was displayed as *unchanged*. As such, through additional edits I could see in the post, I have single handidly rejected your edits, here. In the same vain, I have single handidly accepted your edits, elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onTriggerEnter` has a typo, and it *should* be `OnTriggerEnter`.

`OnTriggerEnter` is invoked whenever there is a collision between a trigger and a rigid body. Thus, the `Collider` object will be referenced by the trigger, and hence, the defined action would be performed as of the function definition by the original question.

Comment: :) This is my own answer to my own question :p No one was answering so I had to when I came up with the real solution. After several hours of patient observation.

Comment: Yeah! Thing is, if you don't mark it as accepted, the question will keep on popping in the recent questions feed once in a while :) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I just realized that after your comment.. I am very new in to this stack exchange forums so I am still learning different functionalities and systems. thanks ! :)

Comment: No worries; I think that in any case you could not have accepted your own answer right away, as a delay is normally required.

Comment: I don't remember quite clearly But it might have been a case.